# Add multiple users as Owner at Team creation through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I have a scrip that successfully creates my Teams with a single owner from a .csv file. I want to be able to add an additional user as owner listed in the .csv.

I need to look up the GroupId from the creation and add a second Owner to the Teams.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$teams = import-csv ‘File_Path’
Foreach($team in $teams)
{
$DisplayName = $teams.'TeamDesc'
$Description = $teams.'Code'
$Visibility = $teams.'Visibility'
$Owner = $teams.’UserPrincipleName’
$GroupId = (Get-Team -DisplayName $team.'TeamDesc').GroupId


New-Team -DisplayName $team.TeamDesc -Owner $team.UserPrincipleName -Description $team.Code -Visibility $team.Visibility
Add-TeamUser -GroupId (Get-Team -DisplayName $team.'TeamDesc').GroupId -User $team.DepartmentChair -Role ‘Owner’ 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, the return from `New-Team` *is* the GroupId (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/new-team?view=teams-ps#outputs). Any reason you're not using this? It would look something like:

```
$groupId = New-Team -DisplayName $team.TeamDesc -Owner $team.UserPrincipleName -Description $team.Code -Visibility $team.Visibility
Add-TeamUser -GroupId $groupId -User $team.DepartmentChair -Role ‘Owner’
```

Comment: I'm trying to create multiple Teams and have the script iterate through my .csv, which is why I have the Foreach loop. I can create the teams without issues, but only with one user as owner. I want to be able to add another user at creation with the owner role without having to copy the GroupId generated into another csv.
It worked fine before I tried adding the second owner, but I'm trying to get both populated in the same run.

I am one step below novice when it comes to using PowerShell, so I apologize if the answer is obvious.

Comment: So I think there's a restriction that it's not possible in one single step, at least not in the underlying API. As a result, what you're doing is fine, by adding the 2nd owner in the 2nd step. As a result, I'm not clear where the problem is? Is the above code not working? If not, what are you seeing?

Comment: I was able to make it work by adding another Foreach loop after the creation step. It's a little clunky but it works.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: yes that sounds good. Glad it's working.

Comment: Please either Mark as Answer or Upvote so others can find this answer if they have a similar issue.